# Backticks within backticks work differently in posts and in comments

Tags: bug, comments, markdown, code, backtick

Writing backticks within backticks works differently in posts and in comments. For example:

```
Use `` `backticks` `` instead of bold text for code-like terms.
```

In posts, this is rendered as the text "backticks" surrounded by backticks in `<code>`.

In comments, this is rendered as 2 backticks in normal style, followed by the text "backticks" in `<code>`, follewed by 2 backticks in normal style.

It would be better if markdown behaved consistently everywhere.

Please don't jump quickly to mark this as duplicate. The similar posts I found are about escaping backticks using backslash, but this case is not using backslash at all.

Comment: This is not a bug. Comments are using a different kind of markdown, by design.

Comment: @ShadowWizard is the difference documented?

Comment: @Cœur [yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHffH.png) :-)